How to install Vue/Vite-Tailwind CSS with Bun instead of Node (NPM)?
I want to install Tailwind CSS with Vue/Vite. But I want to do it with Bun instead of Node or Deno.
I've tried to install it but I can't. Please let me know how to install Vue/Vite and Tailwind CSS with Bun and also the config of Tailwind CSS.

What have you tried, any error?
You can follow Tailwind docs to create it.
Replace npm with bun and replace npx with bunx.
bun create vite@latest my-project -- --template vue
cd my-project

bun install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer
bunx tailwindcss init -p

Configure vue path in tailwind.config.js
  content: [
    "./index.html",
    "./src/**/*.{vue,js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],

Import tailwind directives in your style.css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;


Thank you. That's really useful.
Now, I can use without node.
